# What happens to old Romulan ships?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, romulan

Romulan ships, unlike Federation starships, run on quantum singularities rather than matter-antimatter reactions.  Although this provides a lot of energy and is extremely efficient, you can't exactly 'turn off' a quantum singularity.  This shouldn't be much of a problem when operating the vessel, **but when it becomes old and is scrapped, or is in need of servicing, what do they do**?  You surely can't leave a quantum singularity continue generating such massive energy!

Comment: Old Romulan ships never die, they just cloak away.

Comment: They go to a nice Romulan farm where they can chase Federation shuttlecraft all day?